# Pandas groupby two columns and plot

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': list('XYZXY'), 'B': range(5,10),'sex': list('mfmff')})
```

I want to plot count of sex male or female based on category from column 'category'.

I tried:
`df.groupby(['category','sex'])['category','sex'].count().plot.bar()`

But this gives:
[image]

How do I get the count of sex per category?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Various Methods of Groupby Plots

### Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': list('XYZXY'),
                   'sex': list('mfmff'),
                   'ThisColumnIsNotUsed': range(5,10)})
df

category sex ThisColumnIsNotUsed
0   X   m   5
1   Y   f   6
2   Z   m   7
3   X   f   8
4   Y   f   9
```

### Using crosstab

```py
pd.crosstab(df['category'],df['sex']).plot.bar()
```

### Using groupby+unstack:

```py
(df.groupby(['sex','category'])
   .count().unstack('sex').plot.bar())
```

### Using pivot_table:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df,index = 'category',
               columns = 'sex',aggfunc ='count').plot.bar()
```

### Using seaborn:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(data=df,x='category',hue='sex')

or,
sns.catplot(data=df,kind='count',x='category',hue='sex')
```

### output

[image]

Comment: Hello , I have a similar problem it would be really helpful if you could please help me out with this -[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083775/set-a-column-as-column-index-pandas-dataframe/65083850#65083850)

Answer (score 9):

IIUC,

```
df.groupby(['category','sex']).B.count().unstack().reset_index()\
.plot.bar(x = 'category', y = ['f', 'm'])
```

[image]

Edit: If you have multiple columns, you can use groupby, count and droplevel.

```
new_df = df.groupby(['category','sex']).count().unstack()
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel()
new_df.reset_index().plot.bar()
```

Comment: @ScottBoston, haha. Great minds?;) Wish you a very happy new year!

Comment: @Vaishali Happy 2019!

Comment: Happy new year to you all guys, also small followup, what to do if I have more than three columns, like `B`, `C`, `D`, etc. ? Can we choose any of the other column, or the chosen column must have unique values ?

Comment: @astro123, pl see the edit. And happy new year to you:)

Comment: everything run smoothly but the figure does not show up, why?

Comment: @Jason Goal, You need plt.show() at the end of the code

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'B', index = 'category', columns = 'sex',
               aggfunc = lambda x: len(x)).plot.bar()
```

which results in exactly the same plot.

[image]