# Set a column as Column Index Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

[image]

Let's say I have this data set and for analysing the trends between male and female literacy across rural and urban region of every state . I need to set index as `Name`
Which I can do as -

```
df.set_index('Name',inplace=True)
```

Now I want to segregate my data into `Rural and Urban`
And expect the ouput as -
[image]

How can I acheive this ?

EDIT: I tried doing it using `groupby`

```
Literacy_States=Literacy_States.groupby(['Name','TRU'])['M_LIT','F_LIT'].count().unstack('TRU').plot.bar()
```

But ouput is :
[image]

Comment: Look into pivot, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997862/pandas-groupby-two-columns-and-plot

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here:
[Matplotlib bar chart that displays the x values for male and females](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186534/matplotlib-bar-chart-that-displays-the-x-values-for-male-and-females)

Instead of Male and Females, you have: Rural and Urban.

Comment: I tried doing it -```pd.pivot_table(Literacy_States,values=['M_LIT','F_LIT'],index='Name',columns='TRU',aggfunc ='count').plot.bar()```  but graph isn't one.    Please check the answer as I have included

Comment: Well the link didn't seem to help ,

Comment: You didn't do exactly what is said in my suggestion. check again your code, you have to group by 'TRU'.

Comment: okay , what do I have to unstack ? I am not getting it

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is use a conditional statement to check whether TRU is rural or urban. Then throw that into a data structure- a list would do which would also make it easy to plot. Let me know if you have any questions or need further clarification!

Comment: I tried doing it -```pd.pivot_table(Literacy_States,values=['M_LIT','F_LIT'],index='Name',columns='TRU',aggfunc ='count').plot.bar()```  but graph isn't one.    Please check the answer as I have included